# Windows cmd move file to android device

Tags: android, cmd, move

I want to move a file called "logger.txt" to an android device connect to my pc.
The text file is currently at "c:\logger.txt" and I want it to go to - "Computer\Nexus 7\Internal storage". There is not drive letter so how do I know where to move it to.
I have tried:

```
move c:\logger.txt Computer\Nexus 7\Internal storage
```

It returns "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ADB ([Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html))

`adb push the_file_you_want_to_push the_directory_on_the_device` will push a file (`the_file_you_want_to_push`) onto the device (in `the_directory_on_the_device`)

To get the name of the_directory_on_the_device, you can use `adb shell` and `ls/cd` command to get a path

ADB executable is in `ADT_DIRECTORY/sdk/platform-tools`

You can also get a file from Android to your computer using `adb pull`

Hope it helps

Comment: thedirectory - it is relative to the device so it will be "Internal storage"?

Comment: You can get the directory name using a file explorer. in my case, it can be /sdcard ou /mnt/sdcard